# Hardy $Hp$ norm of similar function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{c_n}{n+1}z^n$, where sequence $c_n \in S^1=\{z:|z|=1\}.$ We observe $H^p$ norm $\|f\|_{H_p}$, where $H^p$ is Hardy space, $1 \leq p < \infty$.
Question: For the fix $p \geq 1$, determine $\min_{c_n \in S^1} \|f\|_{H^p}$ and $\max_{c_n \in S^1}\|f\|_{H^p}$ ?

Comment: Looks great but what on Earth makes you think that there is a nice closed form answer for an arbitrary $p$? If you are willing to settle for less than the exact values, it will be helpful to tell us how much you really want. As written, it looks hopeless except for a few trivial cases (maximum for even integer $p$, etc.)

Comment: Any idea for p=1 or p=3.

Comment: For the exact values, you mean? Of course, not (unless you want to invest time in the computer search and get some meaningless sequences of digits).. How much do you really want?